# how do I access graphql params in prisma extension of a nestjs application

Tags: graphql, nestjs, prisma

I have a nestjs-graphql-prisma application where I have created a prisma query extension which filters out deleted users. I now want to conditionally not apply the prisma query extension when a particular param is send in the request.

I am unable to find a way to get the requested param into the prisma extension to show even the deleted users